# Trim only the strings that contain certain words and adds them to a string list in c#

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to trim the follwing strings in a list:

```
myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE 1/2"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE is selected only display 1/2
myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE 1/4"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE is selected only display 1/4
myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS SUGAR"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS is selected only display SUGAR
myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS BUTTER"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS is selected only display BUTTER
```

Like the comments in the code indicate if the text PINEAPPLE PIE is selected I want to display only 1/2 and 1/4 to the terminal but I get the following output beacuse the other two strings in the list also contain the text PINEAPPLE PIE:

```
1/2
1/4
INGREDIENTS SUGAR
INGREDIENTS BUTTER
```

How can I get the following output?:

```
1/2
1/4
```

Here is my sample code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> myList1 = new List<string>();
            List<string> myList2 = new List<string>();

            myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE 1/2"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE is selected only display 1/2
            myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE 1/4"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE is selected only display 1/4
            myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS SUGAR"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS is selected only display SUGAR
            myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS BUTTER"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS is selected only display BUTTER

            string selectedText = "PINEAPPLE PIE";

            foreach (string item in myList1)
            {
                if (item.Contains(selectedText))
                {
                    string tmp = item.Replace(selectedText, String.Empty);
                    myList2.Add(tmp.Trim()); // Expecting to add "1/2" & "1/4" only, NOT "INGREDIENTS SUGAR" & "INGREDIENTS BUTTER"
                }
            }
            // Display the contents of myList2
            foreach (string item in myList2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope somebody can help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't called trimming, it's removing and or replace.. Also contains will not work here, it would include all. Also what you are showing isnt a real case, you know what items you want so put them in that list...

Comment: If you could explain how the selectedtext may get set, you may get an answer, otherwise much of the code is irrelevant. To be frank, create a class that represents a receipe along with its ingredients and measurements etc...

Comment: You need to set prioritization for filtering out "PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS" from just when "PINEAPPLE PIE" ... so, my recommendation would be to check if the selected text is "PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS" first, and if not, you know then "PINEAPPLE PIE ..." is the target item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: You need a way to distinguish between the list items you want to add and those you don't want to.

In your case its `"INGREDIENTS"`, so just check if it's part of the string or not:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> myList1 = new List<string>();
    List<string> myList2 = new List<string>();
    myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE 1/2"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE is selected only display 1/2
    myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE 1/4"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE is selected only display 1/4
    myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS SUGAR"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS is selected only display SUGAR
    myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS BUTTER"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS is selected only display BUTTER

    string selectedText = "PINEAPPLE PIE";
    string selectedText2 = "PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS";
    foreach (string item in myList1)
    {
        if (item.Contains(selectedText) && !item.Contains(selectedText2))
        {
            string tmp = item.Replace(selectedText, String.Empty);
            myList2.Add(tmp.Trim()); // Expecting to add "1/2" & "1/4" only, NOT "INGREDIENTS SUGAR" & "INGREDIENTS BUTTER"
        }
    }
    // Display the contents of myList2
    foreach (string item in myList2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
   var myList = new List<string>()
        {
            "PINEAPPLE PIE 1/2",
            "PINEAPPLE PIE 1/4",
            "PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS SUGAR",
            "PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS BUTTER"
        };


        // This Regex (Regular expressions) pattern matches the fraction (single digits, like 1/2)
        // OR the word INGREDIENTS followed by any word
        var pattern = @"\d/\d|INGREDIENTS \w*";

        // Use Linq to create a new list
        var result = myList
            .Select(i =>
                // Use Regex to extract something like this: 1/2 or something like this: INGREDIENTS SUGAR
                Regex.Match(i, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                    .Value // <- I am assuming that ingoring case is needed
                    // Remove the word INGREDIENTES from the result.
                    .Replace("INGREDIENTS ", ""))
            // Convert this result to a list
            .ToList();

        // See if the result is correct
        foreach (var extractedText in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(extractedText);
            // OUTPUT:
            // 1/2
            // 1/4
            // SUGAR
            // BUTTER
        }

        /*
         * var pattern = @"\d/\d|INGREDIENTS \w*";
         * \d: any digit
         * /: followed by slash
         * \d: any digit
         * |: OR
         * INGREDIENTES: The word INGREDIENTS
         * \w*: Any word character any times, this ends in case there is another word because space is not
         * a word character, so, for example, this: INGREDIENTS SUGAR JUST A LITTLE, Will match this: INGREDIENTS SUGAR
         */
    }
```

[Regular expression language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to distinguish matches based on the shortest matching string (i.e. length of a string).

If that's the case, this would be one way to go about it:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> myList1 = new List<string>();
        List<string> myList2 = new List<string>();
        myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE 1/2"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE is selected only display 1/2
        myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE 1/4"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE is selected only display 1/4
        myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS SUGAR"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS is selected only display SUGAR
        myList1.Add("PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS BUTTER"); // if text PINEAPPLE PIE INGREDIENTS is selected only display BUTTER
        string selectedText = "PINEAPPLE PIE";
        string shortestMatchingString = "";
        foreach (string item in myList1)
        {
            if (item.Contains(selectedText))
            {
                if (shortestMatchingString.Length == 0)
                { // is this the first match we make?
                    shortestMatchingString = item;
                    myList2.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item.Length < shortestMatchingString.Length)
                    { // is this match shorter in length than the prev. shortest match found
                        shortestMatchingString = item;
                        myList2.Clear();
                        myList2.Add(item);
                    }
                    else if (item.Length == shortestMatchingString.Length)
                    { // this is the 2nd match that is the same in length
                        myList2.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Display the contents of myList2
        foreach (string item in myList2) // here, you can trim the selectedText from each item
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```